# merging 2 Pandas Dataframes reduces the dataset length

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I want to merge the following pandas Datadrame: first_df and second_df

```
>>> len(first_df)
813

>>> len(second_df)
813
```

To merge it I'm using:

```
third_df = pd.merge(first_df, second_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But the size of third_df is not the same:

```
>>> len(third_df)
788
```

How come third_df doesn't have the same size???

Comment: the default merge type is 'inner' this means where in your case the index values are present in both dfs, if you wanted the union of all index values then you could pass param `how='outer'`, or `left` or `right` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

Comment: You should be able to tell if the indices match by doing `first_df.index == second_df.index`, it'll probably return `False`, you'll have to decide what you want to do with the non-matching index values